# Installing Java 8 on ubuntu 14.04

Tags: 14.04

I am trying to add the webupd8team Java PPA repository on my system (Ubuntu 14.04) but I am getting the following error:

```
Cannot add PPA: 'ppa:webupd8team/java'.  
Please check that the PPA name or format is correct.
```

How can I fix this problem?

Comment: What commands do you run?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How did you try to add it?

The correct syntax is: `sudo add-apt-repository ppa:webupd8team/java`.

This should work fine.

Comment: I have tried the same command but it's not working.

Answer (score 0):

You can use these commands to install Java 8

```
su -
echo "deb http://ppa.launchpad.net/webupd8team/java/ubuntu xenial main" | tee /etc/apt/sources.list.d/webupd8team-java.list
echo "deb-src http://ppa.launchpad.net/webupd8team/java/ubuntu xenial main" | tee -a /etc/apt/sources.list.d/webupd8team-java.list
apt-key adv --keyserver hkp://keyserver.ubuntu.com:80 --recv-keys EEA14886
apt-get update
apt-get install oracle-java8-installer
```

Answer (score 0):

If you don't care which kind of Java you get, I would recommend you to simply install the OpenJDK Java Runtime Environment instead of the one from Oracle. It's provided in the standard repositories and can simply be installed using this command:

```
sudo apt-get install openjdk-8-jre
```